# How can I rotate circles in an SVG donut chart?

Tags: javascript, math, svg

I'm in the process of building a donut chart that is rendered on the server. I got some help in the math around positioning the labels to the center of donut slice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672591/calculating-svg-donut-slice-label-position-server-side). That solution works well but I'm having another problem with my chart. I don't know how to rotate each svg circle using my current math formula. I can rotate each slice using `stroke-dashoffset` but then the text isn't following the slice around the chart.

> How can I rotate each slice of the donut chart so that they don't
>   overlap while still keeping the label in the center of the slice?

I *think* I need to adjust the angle, I'm just unsure how.

Here's what It currently looks like
[image]

Here's what I'd like it to look like
[image]

Here's the code sandbox I'm working out of https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-feather-5yyr3.

Comment: The easiest is to use transform matrix on a `<g>`  object covering all the stuff you want to rotate so slice and its text ... take a look at this [Getting SVG d after transform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50406130/2521214)

Comment: In this example the easiest way to do it would be setting a `stroke-dashoffset` of 25% for the second circle. However if what you have in mind is a pie chart I would do it in a different way. Instead of using dashes I would draw a path for every slice.

Comment: But the rotate transform will rotate the texts as well ..